# WordPress - Combining the Edit Media Screen with the Links Manager?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Is there a way to somehow integrate the link manager into the media edit screen? So, if a user uploads or replaces a media item, he/she can also add it to a link category from the edit media screen. I now I can register a tab meta box with with the code below but, for some reason, I can't get it to work with the link category taxonomy.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function add_links_category_for_attachments() {
     register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'link_category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_links_category_for_attachments' );`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in your function file:

```
function add_links_category_for_attachments() {
     register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'link_category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_links_category_for_attachments' );`
```